# Hide Folder Path and File Names in Browser Bar

Tags: nginx

I have a very simple static site hosted on nginx.

Everything works fine, but I would like to clean up the path showed in the browser bar so that it only shows `example.com` instead of `example.com/index.html#someanchor`

The site has several subpages in their own HTML-files, but I would still prefer to always just show the "root domain".

This problem seems to be very elusive as I can't find a single hit on Google on how to do this.

Here's the server block from my sites-available config file:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;


        root /var/www/example.com;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name example.com;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

}
```

Comment: I've never done this myself but I found this guide on "url rewrites" or "pretty urls" which seems relevant: https://www.codesmite.com/article/clean-url-rewrites-using-nginx. Hope this helps!

Comment: This is something you do in your Single Page App framework, not in nginx.

Comment: Took a long time for screen readers to understand how browsers work. Please do not break it again! Instead of hiding the path, make sure all path elements & anchors in the path have meaningful names.